# how to compare: a file from excel and some text in python

Tags: python, excel, file

I have some homework which i have to complete before the holidays- it's really stressing me out. What i am trying to do consists of me making a program in python which takes in a vehicle number plate. If the vehicle number plate matches with the one of the plates in an excel file, it print out all the details from that specific vehicle number plate. 
So, basically i need the python program to read the excel file, compare it to the text entered in the python shell and print out everything to do with that vehicle number plate from the excel file.
I bet its a simple code but i have been struggling with this task for a while, if you could help me, i will be very happy :).
Here is what I've done so far:
I hope what i have written makes sense

Here's an example of what i wrote in my code:

```
import filecmp

import csv

v_n_p = input("Enter the vehicle number plate: ").lower()

if v_n_p == "HS16SRI":
    f = open('test.xls')
    filecmp.cmp(colA, (v_n_p))
    colA = (0,1)
    print (colA)
else:
    print (" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have I can try to point you into the right direction.
First of all, you are importing csv, I presume you will save the xls file as a csv and then open it. Your input is fine, but then you check for a specific case of input. The input has to be HS16SRI, in order for the program to do anything.
Your program should simply open the file right after a plate number has been entered. Second, make a loop that goes through everything in your test.xls(which should really be a csv?) by going through I mean every row and column, since I do not know the structure of your input file that is all I can recommend.

If you provide us with a little more detail maybe we can help you more, but keep in mind this is your homework assignment and we should not be doing this for you as you will not learn anything :)

-Use this to help understand how to parse a CSV: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

-You might want to use this library if you have to keep everything as a excel file:
http://www.python-excel.org/